# Strawberry Perl - Error Message: This package requires a C compiler

Tags: perl, compiler-errors, strawberry-perl

I have Strawberry Perl May 2016 (5.24.0) 32bit PortableZIP edition. I have only unzipped it; there are no changes otherwise.

When i want to install modules with cpan i got the follow error:

```
C:\Fhem\perl\bin>cpan -i Net::SSLeay
Loading internal null logger. Install Log::Log4perl for logging messages
CPAN: CPAN::SQLite loaded ok (v0.211)
Database was generated on Tue, 13 Dec 2016 13:41:47 GMT

Running install for module 'Net::SSLeay'
CPAN: LWP::UserAgent loaded ok (v6.15)
CPAN: Time::HiRes loaded ok (v1.9733)
Fetching with LWP:
http://cpan.strawberryperl.com/authors/id/M/MI/MIKEM/Net-SSLeay-1.78.tar.gz
CPAN: YAML::XS loaded ok (v0.62)
CPAN: Digest::SHA loaded ok (v5.95)
Fetching with LWP:
http://cpan.strawberryperl.com/authors/id/M/MI/MIKEM/CHECKSUMS
CPAN: Compress::Zlib loaded ok (v2.069)
Checksum for C:\Fhem\cpan\sources\authors\id\M\MI\MIKEM\Net-SSLeay-1.78.tar.gz ok
CPAN: Archive::Tar loaded ok (v2.06)
CPAN: File::Temp loaded ok (v0.2304)
CPAN: CPAN::Meta::Requirements loaded ok (v2.140)
CPAN: Parse::CPAN::Meta loaded ok (v1.4417)
CPAN: CPAN::Meta loaded ok (v2.150005)
CPAN: Module::CoreList loaded ok (v5.20160507)
Configuring M/MI/MIKEM/Net-SSLeay-1.78.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
Unresolvable missing external dependency.
This package requires a C compiler.
NA: Unable to build distribution on this platform.
No 'Makefile' created  MIKEM/Net-SSLeay-1.78.tar.gz
  C:\Fhem\perl\bin\perl.exe Makefile.PL -- NOT OK
Stopping: 'install' failed for 'Net::SSLeay'.
```

Seems to be no compiler found. What must I do to fix this?

Comment: Aren't there any post-install scripts to run when using a ZIP version of Strawberry?

Comment: @VesaKarjalinen: No. The whole point of the *PortableZIP* version is that there is no installation process. It provides a command file which opens a new command prompt window with all the necessary settings enabled just for the life of that window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you are running perl and cpan directly from the command prompt?

You should read the contents of the `README.txt` file in the distribution, where it tells you to run
`c:\myperl\portableshell.bat` before using any of the utilities

*I hope it's clear that you must change `c:\myperl` to the folder where you unzipped the distribution*

There are three subdirectories of the unzipped volume which need to be in the `PATH` before everything will work, and the `.bat` file will set those up temporarily for you. If you want something more permanent then the `README.txt` file explains how to  do that, but you should probably run a proper installed version instead

Comment: Ty very much, made my day :-). Sry for not reading readme...Next time i will do first! Followed your guide and the readme and it really works ;-).

Comment: @l05443: You can make things a whole lot easier by selecting `portableshell.bat` in File Manager, then using a *right-click* to drag and drop it to the desktop. If you then select `Create shortcuts here` from the context menu then you will have a desktop shortcut that you can double-click to start the portable Perl environment. Highlight the shortcut and press `F2` to rename it to something more useful.